# Vagrant cannot vagrant up the box packaged from ubuntu xenial64 16.04

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-16.04

I have a custom vagrant box based on the offcial box [ubuntu 16.04](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/xenial64).

I simplly run like this to get the packaged box.

```
vagrant init ubuntu/xenial64; vagrant up --provider virtualbox
vagrant up 
vagrant ssh  # enter the virtual machine and do some custom change on it
vagrant halt

vagrant package --vagrantfile Vagrantfile  --output custom_ubuntu1604.box
```

and then i copy the file `custom_ubuntu1604.box` to  another directory, i use the box like this:

```
vagrant box add ubuntu1604base custom_ubuntu1604.box 
vagrant init ubuntu1604base
vagrant up # at this point the machine will be stopped at "Started Journal Servie"
```

my new virtualbox machine base on the new packaged box will stop at:

[the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vzr3.png)

And finally it timed out:

> Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
>   Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within the
>   configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.
>
> If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that Vagrant
>   had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors are
>   usually good hints as to what may be wrong.
>
> If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
>   working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
>   problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes. Verify
>   that authentication configurations are also setup properly, as well.
>
> If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
>   the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

Comment: _enter the virtual machine and do some custom change on it_ thats the thing, what did you change ? did you change anything in the etc script ? did you install any software, something ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set config.vm.boot_timeout in Vagrantfile more than default e.x.600. From my experience I found out it take a long time at the first time to connecting guest machine.

For example

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox"
    config.vm.boot_timeout = 600
end
```